# How can Apache IoTDB replicate batch of data and change timestamps?

Tags: timestamp, replicate, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Now I need a set of historical data in Apache IoTDB to train data models, so I decide to replicate the current stored data and modify the timestamps. I wonder how can IoTDB efficiently replicate large amount of data?

Anyone know that? Help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.